# Having diffculty getting jquery.mobile-1.0.1 to run in my iPhone

Tags: jquery-mobile

Working with jquery mobile plugin (jquery.mobile-1.0.1) has anyone every had any trouble with getting the code to properly run? If so, what problems did you have and how did you get those matters resolved?

Please advise,

Thank You.....

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>

<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>I'm a Mobile Optimized Webpage</p>
    </div>
</div>​
```

That's pretty much the easiest hello world example you can make. Your question is not very specific (e.g. `what have you done so far?`) so I can't get any more specific with my answer at the moment.

Here is a demo of the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/tKECJ/

Comment: I have a website setup with images that transition us effects in jQuery(either from right to left) using a .click(event). I am trying to use the same site for when you are browsing to it via iPhone or Android you can just move the images with your finger(s) rather than using the .click(event). I have downloaded jQuery mobile.